# How can I rotate an object that is falling and pulled?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have balls falling (gravity) in my game, and in its Update method I've also added a slight pull, as the wind was blowing:

```
transform.Translate(new Vector3(sidewaysDrag,0));
```

Now, I want to rotate my GameOBject around the Z axis as well (its a 2D game), ive tried:

```
transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * 200);
```

But I guess my anchor is wrong, because instead of rotating around itself the whole object is rotating in a very big curve. The rotation is correct if I comment out the translation...

Comment: Is the rotation correct if you remove the translations?

Comment: Is the zero point you're rotating around relative to *the object rotating* or *the coordinate system its in*?

Comment: @Eric Lippert I'm using another way to rotate, see the updated edit. And it works if I dont translate.

Comment: If you have both the translation and the rotation, is it rotating around the point that it was at *before* the translation?

Comment: Do it on `FixedUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

Put your ball object under another empty object(parent).

And translate parent, rotate ball.

or translate ball's world position, rotate ball's localRotation

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using Vector3.forward, which actually points to Z-axis in world space, you need Z-axis in local space, you can get that by doing `transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);`